# Is my proof right: Prove that $f(n)=3\times 2^n +(-1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be defined by $f(1)=5, f(2)=13$, and for $n\geq 2 , f(n)=2f(n-2)+f(n-1)$.Prove that $f(n)=3\times 2^n +(-1)^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Proof:

Let $n=1$, so $f(1)=3\times 2^1 +(-1)^1=5\implies 5=5$, thus $P(1)$ is true.

Let $n=2$, so $f(2)=3\times 2^2 +(-1)^2=13\implies 13=13$, thus $P(2)$ is true.

Assume $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $2f(k-2)+f(k-1)=3\times 2^k +(-1)^k$ is true. So since $2(2f(k-2)+f(k-1))=2(3\times 2^k +(-1)^k) \implies 3\times 2^{k+1} +2(-1)^{k} \implies (3\times 2^{k+1} +2(-1)^{k})(-1)\implies (-3\times 2^{k+1} +2(-1)^{k+1})$.

Thus by PMI, $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: The equation $f(n) = 2f(n) + f(n+1)$ doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: you wrote  $n\geq 2 , f(n)=2f(n)+f(n+1),$ which just says $f(n+1) = -f(n)$

Comment: Um... you never actually stated what $P(n)$ says.  You've shown that if you assume what you are trying to prove is true, then the assumption you were given (and don't need to prove) is true. You need to do the exact opposite.  Show that if what you were give is true, then what you want to prove is true

Comment: One user noted that you do not state the use of the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is not correct. In your induction step you assume $f(n) = 2f(n) + f(n+1) = 3 \times 2^n + (-1)^n$ is correct for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But you didn't check the base case (i.e $n = 3$).

Upon checking that, you will discover the proposition is not true.
Also you multiplication by $1^k$ is not correct. ($\forall k \in \mathbb{N},\  1^k \cdot a = a$)